# Why Low Memory Make Colorbar Unresponsive in Matlab Figures?

Tags: matlab, memory

Condition: colorbar is not about 50% of pictures if loop run without pauses; if I put breakpoints and run it step-wise, all colorbars occur; I think this is some stability/memory problem

Pseudocode

```
i=1;
while (i < 3);

    figure('Visible', 'off');
    hax=axes();
    image('Parent',hax);

    % Do heavy computation here; see the warning below for it. 
    a=rand(1,20000); 
    b=rand(1,20000);
    C=rand(20000,20000);     
    imagesc(a,b,C);
    colorbar(hax)        

    %% Unsuccessful attempts
    %drawnow % does not help
    %pause(1) % does not help

    homedir=char(java.lang.System.getProperty('user.home')); % all systems
    filename=fullfile(home, sprintf('/Desktop/%d', i));
    export_fig(filename, '-png', '-q101', '-a1', '-m1', ...
        '-CMYK', '-nocrop', '-dpng', hax);

    i=i+1;

end
```

Error message after which colorbars are gone, indicating a memory problem

```
Warning: print2array generating a 46.1M pixel image.
This could be slow and might also cause memory
problems.
```

- Suever. Command `drawnow` after `colorbar` does not help.

System: Linux Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit
Matlab: 2016a
Hardware: Macbook Air 2013-mid

Comment: Put a `drawnow` after you call `colorbar`. The issue is that without pauses, there is no time for the renderer to actually draw the colorbar to the screen.

Comment: Give us a [mcve] that actually demonstrates the issue. The code as written is unrunnable unless you literally just want the default `image` to show.

Comment: It seems you forgot to edit the question with the actual code. We don't want pseudo code because that doesn't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Try specifying an explicit axes when creating your image and colorbar

Comment: @Suever See the body. The problem is caused by low memory. I have heavy computation inside the loop. Somehow, Matlab avoids then figure things but completes computation successfully. Do you understand why?

Comment: `gca` is not explicit. That's simply the current axes. create an axes with `hax = axes('Parent', hfig);` then create the colorbar and iamge using `image('Parent', hax); colorbar(hax)`

Comment: Again, show us the ACTUAL code. We don't get any memory issues with the code you're provided.

Comment: @Suever Now, some code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Matlab's internal problem. If you run short in memory, the computation and graphics become unstable in some components, which I cannot profile and understand because closed system. 
Just use real data with difficult matrix computations to reproduce the error. 
I extended Memory with Swap as described in the thread [How to Allocate More Space to Swap and Increase its Size Greater than Ram?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/297767/16920) from 8 GB to 36 GB, and no errors now.